# Extracting certain properties from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that contains many properties.
I need to extract only some of those properties for an array. The commonalities between the properties I need to extract are that `myObject.property.type` will return 'integer' - but I also need to extract one more property that would return 'string'. Then, I will transform this object into an array using the Object.keys() function.

I'm looking for some efficient and stylish ways to do this.

What I have:

```
      myObject: {
        badProperty1:  {type: 'object'},
        goodProperty1: {type: 'integer'},
        badProperty2:  {type: 'object'},
        goodProperty2: {type: 'string'},
        badProperty3:  {type: 'object'},
        goodProperty3: {type: 'integer'},
      }
```

What I want:

```
myArray = ['goodProperty1', 'goodProperty2', 'goodProperty3']
```

Comment: Are they `BigInt`s or `number`s? There is no `integer` type. If they are numbers, are there any other numbers that you do not want?

Comment: You can use `Object.entries` and then `filter`

Comment: If you can just get numbers plus one extra prop you can just do this: `Object.keys( myObject ).filter( key => key === 'goodProperty2' || typeof myObject[key] === 'number' )` where `goodProperty2` is the name of the one extra property you want

Comment: Clarification for the type: typeof any of these properties would return an object; the "type" is constructed manually within that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at first get all the keys, then filter them by a `type` property value of the corresponding object for that key in the parent object. For example:

```js
let myObject = {
  badProperty1:  {type: 'object'},
  goodProperty1: {type: 'integer'},
  badProperty2:  {type: 'object'},
  goodProperty2: {type: 'string'},
  badProperty3:  {type: 'object'},
  goodProperty3: {type: 'integer'},
};

let result = Object.keys(myObject).filter(key => ['integer', 'string'].includes(myObject[key].type));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, falinsky. I clarified the structure of the object further in a comment under my original post:

The object needs to stay intact before I filter through the array as the "types" are constructed within each property. In other words, typeof ```someObject[key]``` will return object for any of these keys.

Comment: @BabyCoder so then please provide a valid example of your object to filter. what is provided now is not a valid one. are those `object` and `integer` supposed to be just strings?

Comment: Yes, I've fixed the object.